# Calling a method when initializing object

Tags: c#, methods, initialization

I'm looking at a way of cleaning up some code. I have the below

```
  var sprite1 = new Sprite(_content.Load<Texture2D>("Content/Block.png"));
  sprite1.Position = new Vector2f(100, 100);
  sprite1.SetInput(Key.A, Key.D, Key.W, Key.S);

  var sprite2 = new Sprite(_content.Load<Texture2D>("Content/Block.png"));
  sprite2.Position = new Vector2f(200, 100);
  sprite2.SetInput(Key.Left, Key.Right, Key.Up, Key.Down);

  _sprites = new List<Sprite>()
  {
    sprite1,
    sprite2,
  };
```

I'd like to initialize the "Sprite" when adding it to the list. But the problem I'm having is the "SetInput" method. That method is optional.

I know this isn't syntactically correct, but below is the sort of thing I'm talking about

```
  _sprites = new List<Sprite>()
  {
    new Sprite(_content.Load<Texture2D>("Content/Block.png")) { Position = new Vector2f(100, 100), SetInput(Key.A, Key.D, Key.W, Key.S) },
  };
```

As you can see I'm attempting to call a method in a similar to way you can set properties.

Here are the ways I'm thinking of getting around it

1. Optional parameters constructor for the keys

   ```
   public Sprite(Texture2D texture, Key? left, Key? right, Key? up, Key? down)
   ```
2. A second constructor with the keys

   ```
   public Sprite(Texture2D texture, Key left, Key right, Key up Key down)
   ```
3. Creating a delegate in the "Sprite" class that is assigned when initialized, and then loop around all the _sprites, calling the method

The code I've put at the start is fine, I'm just wondering if there is a 'better' way?

Thanks.

Comment: A second constructor would be the most expected API.

Comment: In this simple case, I’d probably go with a second constructor. For classes with a lot of options, I generally use a builder class with method chaining: `new Builder(<mandatory arguments>).Position(...).Input(...).Build()`

Comment: Of course, you also can create a wrapper class `Input` that holds four keys and then add a property `Sprite.Input`, which replaces `SetInput`.

Comment: Thanks, @Lumen. That's the option I have gone for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating Input class to cleanup it?

```
internal class Sprite
{
    public Input Input { get; set; }
    ... 
}

internal class Input
{
    public Key Left { get; private set; }
    public Key Right { get; private set; }
    public Key Up { get; private set; }
    public Key Down { get; private set; }

    public Input(Key left, Key right, Key up, Key down)
    {
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
        Up = up;
        Down = down;
    }
}
```

then you'll get exactly what you want

```
_sprites = new List<Sprite>()
{
    new Sprite(_content.Load<Texture2D>("Content/Block.png")) 
    { 
         Position = new Vector2f(100, 100), 
         Input = new Input(Key.A, Key.D, Key.W, Key.S),
    },
 };
```

Comment: I see, I see. So this is what Lumen was talking about. I like it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use so called "fluent" interface:

```
public class Sprite {
     public Sprite SetPosition(Vector2f vector) {
         // set
         return this;
     }

     public Sprite SetInput(Key left, Key right, Key up Key down) {
         // set
         return this;
     }
}
```

Which can be used like this

```
 _sprites = new List<Sprite>()
  {
      new Sprite(_content.Load<Texture2D>("Content/Block.png"))
          .SetPosition(new Vector2f(100, 100))
          .SetInput(Key.A, Key.D, Key.W, Key.S)
  };
```

Whether it is "better" is a matter of taste, but it's definetly an option.

Comment: I do like what you're saying here, and I will keep this is mind for the future as I've never thought of anything like that before, and shall research some more. Thanks for that!

Comment: That's called Fluent Interface (not "api" as I mentioned in answer), so googling by this keywords will do :)